# Работа со слоями в paperjs

Tags: javascript

Весь гугл облазила, никак не могу понять как работать со слоями в paperjs.

Мне нужен пример как один из слоев спрятать, а другой показать. Как понять какой из слоев активный или сделать активным нужный мне слой?

Все, что у меня сейчас есть это:

```
let newLayer = new paper.Layer();
newLayer.activate();

arr.forEach(el1 => {
    newLayer.addChild(el1)
})
```

То есть, на нем должны быть только элементы из arr, но если посмотреть в консоль, то она покажет, что там намного больше объектов.

Ребят, киньте что-нибудь. Дока не особо помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слои находятся в массиве `paper.project.layers` для добавления можно создать экземпляр `Layer` с опцией `insert` равной `true`. Активный слой находится в поле  `project.activeLayer`, для активации слоя используется его метод `.activate()`

Ниже в примере я создаю две окружности в слое по умолчанию `Layer1` и дополнительном слое `Layer2` управление ими происходит через чекбоксы, которые влияют на видимость слоев.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('example');
paper.setup(canvas);
const { Path, Point, Layer, project } = paper;

const createLayer = () => {
  const newLayer = new Layer({insert: true});
  return newLayer;
}

const createCircle = ({x, y, radius, color}) => {
  const circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(x, y), radius);
  circle.fillColor = color;
}

const changeVisibleLayers = ({target}) =>{
  const names = ['l1', 'l2']  
  const index = names.indexOf(target.name)
  paper.project.layers[index].visible = target.checked;
}  

const layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1'); 
const layer2 = document.getElementById('layer2');

layer1.addEventListener('change', changeVisibleLayers, false)
layer2.addEventListener('change', changeVisibleLayers, false)

createCircle({x: 45, y: 80, radius: 45, color:'orange'})

const newLayer = createLayer()
newLayer.activate();

const arr = [
  createCircle({x: 60 + 45, y: 80, radius: 45, color:'pink'}),
  createCircle({x: 60 + 30, y: 80, radius: 30, color:'red'}),
  createCircle({x: 60 + 20, y: 80, radius: 20, color:'white'})
]

arr.forEach(el => {
    newLayer.addChild(el)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.15/paper-core.min.js" integrity="sha512-n8kxMM6jgawwNHl1HJmOXz+l8bMYaq0SrYrbCijlUnUUNXuD4ajzKmdXSTFarH3PViz54jfiSNUUAfTOhIDmRg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.15/paper-full.min.js" integrity="sha512-ovjLI1ZcZe6bw+ImQ21r+sv8q/Vwob2kq7tFidK6E1LWfi0T4uobbmpfEU1//a9h9o5Kkt+MnMWf6rWlg0EiMw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div style="display:flex">
  <canvas id="example" width="200"></canvas>
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
      <input id="layer1" name="l1"  type="checkbox" checked >Layer1</input>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="layer2" name="l2" type="checkbox" checked>Layer2</input>  
    </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо тебе огроменное!

Comment: пожалуйста, успехов в освоении